# Send email to arraylist retrieved from database

Tags: java, sql-server, email, arraylist

I am working on a project where I am required to retrieve email addresses from database and then send an email to them. I have retrieved those email addresses in arraylist. Like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javaapplication1.Person;

public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Person> personlist = new ArrayList<Person>();
        //List<Person> personlist = new List<Person>();
        try {


            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","gsjsc","gsjschanna");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();

            ResultSet srs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person2");
            while (srs.next()) {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setName(srs.getString("name"));
                person.setJobtitle(srs.getString("jobtitle"));
               // person.setFrequentflyer(srs.getInt("frequentflyer"));
                personlist.add(person);
            }

            System.out.println(personlist.size());
            for (int a=0;a<personlist.size();a++)
            {
            System.out.println(personlist.get(a).getName());
            System.out.println(personlist.get(a).getJobtitle());
            // System.out.println(personlist.get(2).getName());
            // System.out.println(personlist.get(3).getName());
            }
            //System.out.println(personlist.get(4));

        //System.out.println(namelist.);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Person.java: contains all setters and getters.

**EDIT**

Now I have to send emails to those email addresses retrieved in the arraylist of object person.
I have got a code for sending emails to multiple recipients in arraylist like this:

```
    package javaapplication1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmailToGroupDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Create a SendEmail object and call start 
  // method to send a mail in Java.
  SendEmailToGroupDemo sendEmailToGroup = new SendEmailToGroupDemo();
  sendEmailToGroup.start();

 }

 private void start() {

  // For establishment of email client with 
  // Google's gmail use below properties.
  // For TLS Connection use below properties
  // Create a Properties object 
  Properties props = new Properties();

  // these properties are required
  // providing smtp auth property to true
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  // providing tls enability
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  // providing the smtp host i.e gmail.com
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  // providing smtp port as 587
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

  // For SSL Connection use below properties

  /*props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
     "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");*/

  // Create Scanner object to take necessary 
  // values from the user.
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please provide your Username for Authentication ...");
  final String Username = scanner.next();

  System.out.println("Please provide your Password for Authentication ...");
  final String Password = scanner.next();

  System.out.println("Please provide Email Address from which you want to send Email ...");
  final String fromEmailAddress = scanner.next();

  System.out.println("Please provide Email Addresses to which you want to send Email ...");
  System.out.println("If you are done type : Done or done");

  // ArrayLists to store email addresses entered by user
  ArrayList< String> emails = (ArrayList< String >) getEmails();

  System.out.println("Please provide Subject for your Email ... ");
  final String subject = scanner.next();

  System.out.println("Please provide Text Message for your Email ... ");
  final String textMessage = scanner.next();

  // Create a Session object based on the properties and 
  // Authenticator object
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
    new LoginAuthenticator(Username,Password));

  try {

   // Create a Message object using the session created above
   Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

   // setting email address to Message from where message is being sent
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress));

   // setting the email addressess to which user wants to send message 
   message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, getEmailsList(emails));

   // setting the subject for the email 
   message.setSubject(subject);

   // setting the text message which user wants to send to recipients
   message.setText(textMessage);

   // Using the Transport class send() method to send message 
   Transport.send(message);

   System.out.println("\nYour Message delivered successfully ....");

  } catch (MessagingException e) {

   throw new RuntimeException(e);

  }  
 }

 // This method takes a list of email addresses and 
 // returns back an array of Address by looping the 
 // list one by one and storing it into Address[]
 private Address[] getEmailsList(ArrayList< String > emails) {

  Address[] emaiAddresses = new Address[emails.size()];

  for (int i =0;i < emails.size();i++) {
   try {
    emaiAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(emails.get(i));
   }
   catch (AddressException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  return emaiAddresses;
 }

 // This method prompts user for email group to which he
 // wants to send message
 public List< String > getEmails() {
  ArrayList< String > emails = new ArrayList< String >();

  int counter = 1;
  String address = "";
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  // looping inifinitely times as long as user enters 
  // emails one by one
  // the while loop breaks when user types done and 
  // press enter.
  while(true) {

   System.out.println("Enter E-Mail : " + counter);
   address = scanner.next();

   if(address.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")){
    break;
   }
   else {
    emails.add(address);
    counter++;
   }
  }

  return emails;
 }
}

// Creating a class for Username and Password authentication
// provided by the user.
class LoginAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
 PasswordAuthentication authentication = null;

 public LoginAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
  authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
 }

 @Override
 protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
  return authentication;
 }
}
```

This one is a whole different code. But works to send an email to group of people. But problem is we have to enter the email addresses manually. Whereas I want to send the mails to the addresses retrieved from class ABC. Somebody can give me an integrated code (for both the classes) , that would be great.

Comment: *Note: Please answer with a full working code, deadline is close.* - lol, good luck with that bud

Comment: your question and your code do not match. Where is the email being set in the Person object? Your other piece of code gets the list of emails from console and does not seem to have any connection with the Person list fetching code.

Comment: `Please answer with a full working code, deadline is close` - I normally edit this sort of rubbish out, but in your case I'll leave it in, so everyone can see it. The bare-faced cheek of it... [read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: halfer , ok removed it, thanks for being so rude to a newbie. But my aim was not to get any priority over anyone ,but to get a full working code as I am already exhausted working on this and I have seen some people posting incomplete code which I find difficult to comprehend

Comment: No, the rudeness is yours - that is exactly the point I am making. You'll understand this once you have read the link I have supplied. You presently have no idea how to treat volunteers, but I hold out hope you can learn!

Answer (score 0):

This should convert a `List` of `Person` in an `ArrayList` of `String` with the emails from all the persons.

```
public ArrayList<String> getEmailsFromPersons(List<Person> persons) {
    ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Person person : persons) {
        String email = person.getEmail();
        if(email != null && !email.trim().isEmpty()) {
            emails.add(email);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have retrieved those email addresses in arraylist. Like this:

I do not see any email being set in the Person object. But would still try to answer your question from what I have understood after your edit. Below code should suit your needs (Please don't mind any errors as I am writing it on the fly without any checking):

```
public class ABC {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<Person> personlist = new ArrayList<Person>();
    // Creating a separate list of emails for Persons
    List<String> personEmails = new ArrayList<String>();

    //List<Person> personlist = new List<Person>();
    try {


        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","gsjsc","gsjschanna");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        ResultSet srs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person2");
        String email = "";
        while (srs.next()) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(srs.getString("name"));
            person.setJobtitle(srs.getString("jobtitle"));
            // person.setFrequentflyer(srs.getInt("frequentflyer"));
            // I am assuming you would be setting email in person like this
            email = srs.getString("email");
            person.setEmail(email);
            // Add the email simultaneously to the separate list
            personEmails.add(email);
            personlist.add(person);
        }

        System.out.println(personlist.size());
        for (int a=0;a<personlist.size();a++)
        {
        System.out.println(personlist.get(a).getName());
        System.out.println(personlist.get(a).getJobtitle());
        // System.out.println(personlist.get(2).getName());
        // System.out.println(personlist.get(3).getName());
        }
        //System.out.println(personlist.get(4));

    //System.out.println(namelist.);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    // call the email sender method of yours with the newly created list
    SendEmailToGroupDemo sendEmailToGroup = new SendEmailToGroupDemo();
    // Obviously, make that start() method public having parameter of type List<String> instead of calling getEmails() within it
    sendEmailToGroup.start(personEmails); 
    // Very little remains to be done, I hope you can figure it out easily
} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks bhai. Did all you mentioned, but got errors in ` message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, getEmailsList(emails));`  as emails cant be resolved . Would be great help if you could post full working code